# How can I classify an email as internal in Outlook when sending it using JavaMail with Java Spring and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, mime-message

How to add confidentiality using mime message .

```java
Message msg = new Message ( session)
msg. Setfrom(….)
msg.setReply(…)
msg. Setsubject(…)
….
```

I tried below and able to get in mail  that “please treat this as private” .
But this is not what ima trying to get
Msg.Setheader (Sensitivity,”private”);

When we sent a mail via Java mail ,I need to  get mail  classified as internal in my outlook .
Can someone please guide me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Message use MimeMessage type.

```java
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
// Set headers for confidentiality
msg.setHeader("Sensitivity", "Company-Confidential");
msg.setHeader("Importance", "High");
msg.setHeader("Priority", "1");
```